# Making a mail hook to send a post request

Tags: email, hook, mutt

I want to do something similar to http://www.mailhooks.com/. When a email is received, it sends a post request to a provided website, but I don't know where to start implementing such a thing. Do textual email interface, such as `mutt` and `pine` allow receive hook, if not what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to use `.procmailrc` or `.forward`. Using either one you can pipe any incoming messages to a program of your choice.

E.g. using procmailrc:

```
:0:
| ~/myprogram
```

The program should then read the message from stdin and perform the post request.